# React component not sending variable value with onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display more than one task using the same react component and a map function. The components is supposed to upload a file and display the file that has been upload or is uploading with an onChange event, an onSubmit event will be added later to send the file to the back-end. Since the component is being dynamically rendered with an onChange event I am sending the li key as a parameter then only rendering the filename to the li that matches based on the key. The issue I am currently having is when I send the key in the onChange the value is not getting to the function. I have even tried setting a state for the key and then pulling that into the function but I get back undefined I have tried 100 other things as well and either get back undefined or 0. This is my first post on here and I am also just a junior dev so I may be missing info needed here if so please let me know.

Here is the code

```
   const onChange = (e, index) => {
        setFilename(e.target.files[0].name)
        setArrFiles([...arrFiles, {key:index, file:e.target.files[0].name} ]) 
    }

    const displayTask = (index) => {
        let upload = []
        arrFiles.forEach(el => {
            if(el.key === index) {
                upload.push(el.file)
            }
        })
        return upload.map((file) => (
            <li key={index}>{file}</li>
        ))
    }
```

```
{database.map((task, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                    <p>{index}</p>
                    <div className="userPortal__tasksContainer">
                        <div className='userPortal__tasksHeader'>
                            <p className='userPortal__tasksHeaderTitle'>{task.taskTitle}</p>
                            <p className='userPortal__tasksHeaderInfo'>{task.taskMessage}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className='userPortal__tasksBodyButtons'>
                            <form className='userPortal__fileUpload'>
                                <input className='userPortal__inputButton' multiple id='file' type="file" onChange={e => onChange(e, index)}/>
                                <label htmlFor='file'>Choose File</label>
                            </form>
                            <button className='userPortal__tasksBodyButton green'>Task Complete</button>
                        </div>
                        <p id='userPortalFooterTitle'>Successfully Uploaded</p>
                        <div className='userPortal__footer'>
                            <ul>
                                {displayTask(index)}
                            </ul> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was like a dummy I hard coded the input ID so when referencing the input field it would only get the hard coded value instead of the index of the component.

Here is the updated form.

```
                           <form className='userPortal__fileUpload'>
                               <input className='userPortal__inputButton' multiple id={index} type="file" onChange={(() => (e) => onChange(e, index))()}/>
                               <label htmlFor={index}>Choose File</label>
                           </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No Do It Like This

```
const onChange = (e, index) => {
      setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
      //  Okay You Need To Filter The State In Order To Get The Object With THe Current Index
      //  Set The File Value Of The Object To e.target.files[0].name
      setArrFiles((state) => {
        const allFiles = state;

        const currentFile = allFiles.filter(
          (file) => parseInt(file.key) === parseInt(index)
        )[0];
        // i converted it to an integer just to prevent further bugs
        currentFile.file = e.target.files[0].name;
        return [allFiles];
      });
    };
```

Comment: I have another function that is doing the filtering I have edited the post to show the displayTask function.
I was getting random errors when using the filter method(I checked 3 times to make I wrote it right) but the issue is still with the index parameter being undefined, which might be why the filter was giving me errors.

Comment: Okay since what displayTask function is doing is only returning an html element.
I do not see how it plays a part in the onClick function

Comment: where does the displayTask function even run ?

Comment: displayTask is rendered when there is a change causing react to re-render which that change is the onChange function. displayTask is just using the state that onChange changed. Which all of that works just fine and display the data on the page but since the index value isn't being sent with either onChange or displayTask it is making the index 0 for all the file keys and then it is displaying them all the file names on task 0 because the the key on the file obj is being set to 0 instead of being set to the index

Comment: dude, the first step to solving your problem is by changing the displayTask function to a component.

capitalize the function and render it as a component, don't run it as a function.

do this <DisplayTask /> instead of {displayTask()}

Comment: Okay that makes sense Ill have to rework it though as it does not render anything now and has no was way of knowing where to display the files since the <DisplayTask /> is no longer taking in the index and even if it was its doesn't pass the index value to the function for some reason. 

Side note thank you for taking the time to help me on this issue.

Comment: the index needs to be passed as a prop to the component.
<DisplayTask props={index:index} />

Comment: Okay dude, i forgot you were using hooks.
You need to change your function and accept the params like this.

const DisplayTask = ({index}) => { your function}

Then pass the props as <DisplayTask index={index}/>.

Don't regard any of the code i posted in the comments earlier. 
It is buggy, try this one

Comment: That looks a lot cleaner thank you, now if I could just figure out why onChange is not getting the index value.

Comment: does the rendered components from <DisplayTask index={index}/> component get the index ?.

Please check and let me know

Comment: when I console.log(props.idx) I get two logs both from line 18 first one logs 0 and second one logs 1. This makes sense as I have two tasks being rendered right now if I remove one it only console.logs 0 which to me says it is getting the index inside the DisplayTask component. But when I console.log(index) inside of onChange it logs 0 no matter what task index is clicked on to be sent

Comment: Okay let's start with step by step debugging give the element with the onChange event an attribute with the value as the index and let's see what you get when you inspect it with the html inspector

``` 
<input className='userPortal__inputButton' multiple id='file' type="file" data-index={index} onChange={e => onChange(e, index)}/>
```

Comment: I added the data-index={index} but I am not sure what I am inspecting as I didn't see anything different from before

Comment: Well we're expecting the data-index attribute to display the index value just to be sure that the component receives the index.

Have You Found A Way To Solve It Yet ?

Comment: The data-index still wasn't sending the index for some reason, so today I am going to rebuild the whole component as I don't see a way for the component to behave the way I want with the way its built now. Thank you for all the help on this issue.